# `df[df['name']=='Penny']` works well while `df[df['sn']=='016']` doesn't, how do I fix it?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to select exact one row from a DataFrame with pandas.

Here is the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'final': {0: 100, 1: 100, 2: 100, 3: 95, 4: 95},
 'name': {0: 'Penny', 1: 'Sheldon', 2: 'Leonard', 3: 'Rajesh', 4: 'Howard'},
 'sn': {0: '016',
  1: '031',
  2: '016',
  3: '001',
  4: '007'}})
df.set_index('sn', inplace=True)
```

When I select the row with `name`, it works well

```
df[df['name']=='Penny']
```

However, `sn`

```
df[df['sn']=='016']
```

throws

> KeyError: 'sn'

Why is that, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is that `sn` represents the index of the Pandas Dataframe rather than a mere column, i.e.

```
df.index.name
> 'sn'
```

which leaves `df.sn` (or, equivalently, `df['sn']`) undefined throwing a `KeyError: 'sn'` when you attempt to access/set it.

Using `df.index` in general and `df[df.index=='016']` in your particular example fixes the issue.

Note, however, that the index value `016` is assigned twice while `Penny` is only used once which leads to different subframes.